# C++11 STL merge using move assignment between 2 maps

Tags: c++, c++11, dictionary, stl

Is it possible to merge map from 1 instance A to another without unnessery calls of copy constructor of B?

```
class A
{
    ...
    A & operator=(A && rhs);

    map<string, B> map;
};

class B
{
    B();
    B & B(B && rhs);
    ... 
}

...

A instanceOfA1;
A instanceOfA2;

B instanceOfB1;
B instanceOfB2;
B instanceOfB3;
B instanceOfB4;

instanceOfA1.map.insert( pair<string, B>("one", instanceOfB1));
instanceOfA1.map.insert( pair<string, B>("two", instanceOfB2));
instanceOfA1.map.insert( pair<string, B>("three", instanceOfB3));

instanceOfA2.map.insert( pair<string, B>("four", instanceOfB4));

instanceOfA2 = instanceOfA1;
```

So that map in instanceOfA2 contains all four instances of B.

EDIT: Fixed instances in code.

Comment: Should it not be `instanceOfA2 = move(instanceOfA1)`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is it possible to merge map from 1 instance A to another without unnessery calls of copy constructor of B?

Unfortunately, no. There was a [proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3645.pdf) to allow elements to be removed from one map and inserted into another, but it was not accepted. There are some plans to revise the paper and make a new proposal in future.

The best you can do is to insert new elements, but make sure they use the move constructor of `B` instead of copying:

```
for (auto& p : A1)
  A2.insert(std::move(p));
```

This can be done with `move_iterator`s too:

```
A2.insert(std::make_move_iterator(A1.begin()), std::make_move_iterator(A1.end()));
```

Note that the `key_type` in a `std::map` is `const`, so the key type can not be moved, only the mapped types (the `B` objects) will be moved. That means `A1` will still contain the same number of elements it had originally, but the `B` objects will be moved-from, and so you probably want to do this afterwards:

```
A1.clear();
```

Comment: Yeah, I was just going to write that in my answer.

Comment: @user657267, yes, but the key in a map is `const` so can't be moved. The mapped type can be moved though.

Comment: That's what OP wants, no?

Comment: @jrok, I assume OP wants the same keys in `A2` as well :) My point is that the keys will be copied, only the mapped values can be moved. If the keys are e.g. `unique_ptr` you're stuck and it won't work.